# Change font of entire document using WordAPI

Tags: office-js

I am trying to change the font style of the entire document using the following code...

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    const body = context.document.body;
    body.font.set({
        name: "Arial"
    });
    return context.sync();
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
          console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    };
 });
```

In console I get the following error:

```
Error: GeneralException: Cannot read property 'VA' of null
Debug info: {"code":"GeneralException","message":"Cannot read property 'VA' of null","errorLocation":"Font.name","statement":"font.name=...;","surroundingStatements":["var root=context.root;","var body=root.body;","// Instantiate {body}","var font=body.font;","// Instantiate {font}","// >>>>>","font.name=...;","// <<<<<"],"fullStatements":["Please enable config.extendedErrorLogging to see full statements."]}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: there are desktop/mac/online/ios environment, on which environment you hit this issue?

Comment: It's on word live

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to understand the problem, it seems to be a problem with the font assignment.
I receive the same error with :

```
let inTextCit = context.document.getSelection().insertText('test', Word.InsertLocation.start);
inTextCit.font.size = 11;
context.sync()
```

The error does not occur if I remove the second line of code.

Comment: Your code is fine. You just need to load the Range properties before changing it with     inTextCit.load('font/size')